# Yii pattern match for URL

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting, custom-url

I need to handle a SEO-friendly URL in my [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com) application. My URL structures in the pattern: "domain.com/url-string/uniqueid". For example:

```
domain.com/properties-in-dubai/325fgd
domain.com/properties-in-USA/4577ds6
domain.com/properties-in-india/567dew
domain.com/apartments-in-anderi-mumbai/645fki
```

The above URL strings and ID are populated by us. When the user access this URL:

1. first need to validate the URL pattern.
2. second extract the I'd and URL string and match with my data store.
3. third when above URL and I'd exist in our data store pass a referenced parameters to existing search page.

Kindly, anyone help me solve this issue and give sleep to me.

Answer (score 1):

First, you add a new rule to your `urlManager` application configuration.

```
'rules' => array(
    '<slug>/<id:\d+>' => 'property/view'
    // ...
)
```

Then you can retrieve the slug and ID in the action:

```
class PropertyController extends CController
{
    public function actionView($slug, $id)
    {
        $id = (int) $id;

        // Check if $id, $slug exist; replace line below
        $exists = true;

        if($exists){
            // Redirect to elsewhere
            $this->redirect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but when I use redirect the Seo friendly URL gets changed. is there possible to maintain the same url on redirect